# Problem replacing dummy synthetic dataset with a csv dataset

Tags: python, list, numpy, dataset

I'm trying to run a code that I have downloaded from Github. The dataset that the code works on is given as:

```
data = np.concatenate(([1] * 8000, [2] * 4000, [3] * 1000, [4] * 500, [5] * 1000, [6] * 1800, [7] * 2000, [8] * 300))
```

If I keep it like this, the code works fine, but if I read a csv instead, it gives me a lot of errors.
I read csv in two ways (neither is working):

Using Pandas:

```
data = pd.read_csv(data_path, header=None)
```

Using csv

```
with open(data_path, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    next(reader)
    data = np.array(list(reader)).astype(float)
```

I have tried some other ways too but none worked.
[This](https://github.com/Samuel-Maddock/pure-LDP/blob/master/example.py) is the code I'm trying to run with the csv file I have.

In order to execute this with a csv file, how do I read a csv so that the data fetched/read is in accordance with the sample data given in the original code? Or is there another solution to it?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using csv file you cant follow this code and you should write your code that at the first read csv as data frame and then work on it.
These are two different methods and you can't merge these two methods together.